# Get specific Data from inside a HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, hash, hashmap, output

First of all I must apologies for I am uncertain how to word my title well.

However the problem I am facing is a continuation of another question that brought me one step closer to completing this particular program. Onto the problem though.

Here is my current output:

```
Income
{Jack=46, Mike=52, Joe=191}
```

These are inside the HashMap and I printed that out, what I need to do though is make this output more presentable and I guess that leads to needing to manipulate/get certain Data from inside the Map and then make it presentable.

The goal I am aiming for is to get my output to look like this:

```
Jack: $191
Mike: $52
Joe: $46
```

I'm still very new to Java and programming in general so I'm just wondering if this is possible or if I have tackled this all from the wrong way in the beginning?

Below is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  String name;
  int leftNum, rightNum;

  //Scan the text file
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(Test3.class.getResourceAsStream("pay.txt"));

  Map < String, Long > nameSumMap = new HashMap < > (3);
  while (scan.hasNext()) { //finds next line
    name = scan.next(); //find the name on the line
    leftNum = scan.nextInt(); //get price
    rightNum = scan.nextInt(); //get quantity

    Long sum = nameSumMap.get(name);
    if (sum == null) { // first time we see "name"
      nameSumMap.put(name, Long.valueOf(leftNum + rightNum));
    } else {
      nameSumMap.put(name, sum + leftNum + rightNum);
    }
  }
  System.out.println("Income");
  System.out.println(nameSumMap); //print out names and total next to them

  //output looks like this ---> {Jack=46, Mike=52, Joe=191}

  //the next problem is how do I get those names on seperate lines
  //and the total next to those names have the symbol $ next to them.
  //Also is it possible to change = into :
  //I need my output to look like below
  /*
      Jack: $191
      Mike: $52
      Joe: $46
  */
}

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to print all map entries sorted by values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well instead of relying on the default `toString()` implementation of `HashMap`, just loop over the entries:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : nameSumMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": $" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: You'll have to forgive me as my understanding is still weak. I've been trying to implement this but I either get a list of every individual line printed from the text file I'm reading or nothing at all? I've tried putting the "For" above my "While" and placing the other half around to try and get it to work?

Comment: @Masch: That code will print every entry that's in your map, in the form `{key}: ${value}`. Now if the contents of your map isn't what you wanted it to be, that's a different question.

Comment: I think I'm starting to see. I'm weak on this Map stuff though but I guess the map has taken everything from the text file and here it has printed out every line with the name and then $number. I don't know if my previous question [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804965/finding-the-total-income-of-3-re-occurring-names-people-in-a-text-file [/link] has lead me to wording this question wrong? Apologies for the trouble I'm causing here btw.

Comment: With the code you've posted, you shouldn't end up with lots of lines. Are you sure you haven't left a `System.out.println` call somewhere in your `while` loop?

Comment: I only get all the lines being read from the text file printed out if the for loop is put inside the while loop. If I take out the 'System.out.println' line I get no output showing. I'm trying not to put the 'for' loop inside the 'while' but I can't seem to get any output using it elsewhere otherwise?

Comment: It should be *after* the `while` loop, but you should be getting entries in your map... it sounds like now would be a very good time to learn to use a debugger, to be honest.

Comment: I placed it after the While Loop like you stated and it has worked perfectly now, sorry for all the questions btw. I'll also start looking into using the debugger as you suggest. Many thanks for the help and advise.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Iterator to loop through the Map and print all of its contents, the below example should work for you.

```
Iterator iterator = nameSumMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
    System.out.println(mapEntry.getKey()
        + ": $" + mapEntry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Don't use iterator explicitly if you don't have any reason for it (like removing some elements). Instead use enhanced-for-loop which can wrap your `while` loop very nicely (take a look at Jon answer). Also don't use raw types.